# Multiple constraint in portfolio optimization using fPortfolio package

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization, finance, portfolio

I am constructing efficient portfolio using multiple constraints: namely long position and minimum weight on given asset=34%(say). I am using the fPortfolio package to do this. According to the manual one can provide compound constraints by creating a string vector. I have some problem with that approach. Here is an example from the fPortfolio manual.

```
library(fPortfolio)
Data = SMALLCAP.RET[,c("BKE", "GG", "GYMB", "KRON")]
Spec = portfolioSpec()
setTargetReturn(Spec) = mean(colMeans(Data))
Constraints = "LongOnly"
efficientPortfolio(Data, Spec, Constraints)
```

This works. However I want to augment this by adding the minimum weight condition

```
Spec = portfolioSpec()  
setTargetReturn(Spec) = mean(colMeans(Data))
Constraints = c("LongOnly","minW[1]=0.34")
efficientPortfolio(Data, Spec, Constraints)
```

The above code doesn't give desired result. I know I am doing something wrong setting the constraint. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it looks like the constraints line.  Page 33 of [the fPortfolio manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fPortfolio/fPortfolio.pdf) says

*Constraints are defined by a character string or a vector of character
strings. Summary Constraints: NULL, "LongOnly", "Short" There are
three special cases, the settings constraints=NULL,
constraints="Short", and constraints="LongOnly". Note, that these
three constraint settings are not allowed to be combined with more
general constraint definitions.*

If you try this

```
library(fPortfolio)
Data = SMALLCAP.RET[,c("BKE", "GG", "GYMB", "KRON")]
Spec = portfolioSpec()  
setTargetReturn(Spec) = mean(colMeans(Data))
Constraints = "minW[1]=0.34"
efficientPortfolio(Data, Spec, Constraints)
```

you get

```
Title:
 MV Efficient Portfolio 
 Estimator:         covEstimator 
 Solver:            solveRquadprog 
 Optimize:          minRisk 
 Constraints:       minW 

Portfolio Weights:
   BKE     GG   GYMB   KRON 
0.3400 0.3390 0.1671 0.1538 

Covariance Risk Budgets:
   BKE     GG   GYMB   KRON 
0.3457 0.3421 0.2120 0.1002 

Target Return and Risks:
  mean     mu    Cov  Sigma   CVaR    VaR 
0.0243 0.0243 0.0962 0.0962 0.1592 0.1117
```

which I think is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks.. I thought as much. This is a huge limitation that one cannot impose more complex restrictions on weights.

Comment: @user227290: You could have `Constraints = "minW=c(0.74,0,0,0)"` or `Constraints = "minW=c(0.74,-0.5,0,-1)"` if you want something more complicated: the former would be "Long only"

Comment: @Henry so the optimizer is set to portfolio variance minimization, but the output additionally provides VaR and CVaR estimates for that portfolio, even though they are not the quantities being minimized?

Answer (score 0):

The comment for the previous response is unfair if I may say so. There is no limitation in how complex your constraints can be...
To your example `Constraints = c("LongOnly", "minW[1]=0.34")`, you can easily implement it as:
`Constraints = c("minW[1:4]=0", "minW[1]=0.34")`
You can add all sorts of (sophisticated) constraints as per the manual. I do agree, the manual is not super clear in terms of how to combine them, but `c(constraint1, constraint2, etc.)` is the correct way.